# Change fill/colour for geom_dotplot or geom_histogram with a continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, continuous

Is it possible to fill ggplot's geom_dotplot with continuous variables?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, fill = disp)) +
  geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

this should be pretty straightforward, but I've tried messing with the groups aes and no success.

The max I can do is to discretize the disp variable but it is not optimal.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, fill = factor(disp))) +
  geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! You have to set `group = variable` within `aes`  (where `variable` is equal to the same column that you're using for `fill` or `color`):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = disp, group = disp)) +
  geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

`geom_dotplot` in away is just like a histogram. You can't set fill/colour there easily as grouping is done. To make it work you have to set `group`.

Example using `geom_histogram`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = disp, group = disp)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, great! As the new dots are unbinned, I managed to bin them again with `geom_dotplot(method = "histodot", binwidth = 1)`. Thanks!